# Strange combination of jQuery mouseenter, mouseleave, and append

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent, mouseover

I've got an interesting issue with combining jQuery's `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events with a call to `append`.  My object is to show extra content when the mouse enters something and then remove it when the mouse leaves.  It's very similar to what happens when you mouse over a tag here on StackExchange.  The sequence is:

- In `mouseenter`, create content and position it by the element under the mouse via `.offset` and `.append`.
- In `mouseleave`, remove that content from the screen.

The element I'm operating on is an `img`, and I'm using jQuery 1.6.2.  The problem is that `.append` somehow triggers `mouseleave`, which is quickly followed by `.mouseenter`, ad infinitum.  It appears as a strange flickering effect on the content being added, as it's removed and re-added repeatedly.  See an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/QX7Dz/8/) on jsFiddle.  Why is this happening, and how do I resolve it?

EDIT: figured it out.  D'oh.  The added content was appearing under the mouse.

Comment: did u try to use mouseover and mouseout ?

Comment: I *think* these types of things are usually appended to the body, absolute positioned, and offscreen. The mouseover simply changes the left/top to below the element. It's already loaded and less intrusive to the dom than add/remove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this happens is that you're adding content where your mouse is.  That new content is not part of your original element so by definition when you show the new DIV your mouse is not over the IMG any more.

One way to solve this would be to use the image as a background of a parent DIV and then append the new DIV to the parent so that the new DIV is a child of the parent.

On a side note is there a reason you chose not to use .hover()?

Here's a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QX7Dz/18/) for how I'd do this.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="papa">
    <div class='myDiv'>
        <div id='divHover'>Hello World</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript/Jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".papa").hover(
      function () {
        $(".myDiv").show();
      },
      function () {
        $(".myDiv").hide();
      }
    );
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.papa {
    background-image:url('http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff');
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
.myDiv {
    display: none;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
#divHover {
    width:100px;
    height:20px;
    background-color:white;
    border:1px solid black;
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
}
```

Comment: I noticed this and updated the question, but I'll give you the points for this.  And I am using `.hover()`, I just didn't transfer that into the jsFiddle.

Comment: @Mr Jefferson LOL thanks!  Just saw your edit.  Sometimes I don't see updates until after I've submitted answers sometimes the updates come in a more timely fashion.